# run php file using command line when i worked on WAMP

Tags: php, wamp

My project name is a waterpump and i want to run waterpump project product.php file using command line then what i have to write ?

I have follow below steps.
Go to run –> type ‘cmd’

change directory to the PHP folder. You might have a different version.
cd C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5

but what i have to write after change directory to the PHP folder?

Comment: You really want to read the manual before posting here... http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the following link. it may help you

```
http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php
```

In windows try this ..

For Linux user, then can use command as below

php product.php